# What programming language does DigiFlow look most like?

Tags: c, fortran, digiflow

DigiFlow is used for image processing for fluid dynamics experiments - [DigiFlow website](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/digiflow/). There is a console within the program which is used for writing macros.

Some example code:

```
    function do_this(variable) {variable += 2};
    output := do_this(5);
```

(output = 7 after running this.)

Comment: I asked about asking about digiflow questions over on meta-SO - [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133848/digiflow-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From assignment and function declaration I'd say it looks like Google's [go language](http://golang.org/). Pascal might be another choice.